# Eslint config file in different folder

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am running eslint from node api cliengine, code below

```
var params = process.argv.splice(2);
var CLIEngine = require("eslint").CLIEngine;
var cli = new CLIEngine({
    config: "./.eslintrc"
});
var report = cli.executeOnFiles(["../../resources/script/modules/accounts/core/utils/roleConstant.js"]);
console.log(report);
console.log(report.results[0].messages);
```

But my config file is in different path `WebContent\dev-addons\eslint-hook\.eslintrc` and my script files for linting is in different location `WebContent/resources/script/modules/accounts/core/utils/roleConstant.js`.

It always says that no config file found while running.

My question is how to tell to cli engine that my config file is located in this location. I don't want to change config file location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise the following steps:

- Use `path.join` to generate paths using the built-in NodeJS [path package](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths). That way you will avoid bugs related to slashes depending on different OS. That package has other useful functions like `resolve`.
- Pass the `configFile` [config option](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#cliengine) to the `CLIEngine` when creating the instance. Make sure your eslint version supports it.

Using the file structure of your paths:

```
const path = require("path")

var cli = new CLIEngine({
    configFile: path.join("..", "..", "dev-addons", "eslint-hook", ".eslintrc")
})
```